# How do I Save and reuse integers

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I want to save how much money a user has and every time they open the app, the value does not change unless it is used. Pretty much when a user buys something at the shop inside the app, the value goes down and and when they come back to the app, the value is where it left off and they can continue to sell and buy things. My code is below. I can't figure out how to save it as an integer so I can bring the number back and reuse it.

```
    var cashCounter = 50

   //user spends in-app money
   //user not has x money

    UserDefaults.standard.set(cashLabel.text, forKey: "cash")


 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let numberObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "cash")
    if let cash = numberObject as? String {
        scoreLabel.text = String(cash)
  }
```

Comment: You are saving a String (cashLabel.text) when you should be saving the cashCounter which is your Integer

Comment: Just use integer for key to load it, create a String from that and add it to your label

Comment: So...it works to a point. I am having an issue where after the user spends money, it automatically changes back to 50 and subtracts it from that. Not the new value that is saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update for swift 3.0

To set Integer Value from USER DEFAULT:

```
 self.setUserDefaultIntegerFromKey("Your Key", value: 1)
```

To get Integer Value from USER DEFAULT:

```
let value = self.getUserDefaultIntegerFromKey("Your Key")
```

Method get Integer Value from USER DEFAULT:

```
func getUserDefaultIntegerFromKey(_ key : String) -> Int
{
    var value : Int = 0

    if  (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key) != nil)
    {
        value = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key) as! Int
        return value
    }
    return value
}
```

Method to set Interer Value from USER DEFAULT:

```
func setUserDefaultIntegerFromKey(_ key : String ,value : Int)
{
    UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey:key)
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

Comment: No need to force synchronize

Comment: User defaults has a method called Integer for key to load integers saved to it.

Comment: @LeoDabus Is calling `synchronize()` is not required? Happens automatically?

Comment: Yes it happens automatically. Calling sync forces the application to write it to disk. Even if the app happens to have not saved it to disk when you try to access it returns the value from cache. From the docs Discussion
Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes.